# How to call IBAction of another UIViewController soon after presentViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

So currently the user is in ViewController2, to transition to ViewController1 the presentViewController is being called.

Soon after ViewController1 opens up, there is an IBAction method that needs to be called.

How can this be accomplished? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Couldn’t you just call it in the did load method?

Comment: Should be in `viewWillAppear(animated:)`, not `viewDidLoad()`. The former will get called only when the VC is loaded into memory, while the latter is called whenever the VC becomes the topmost (i.e. visible) view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view controller can call it itself in either viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

```
self.myAction()
```

If the view controller is exclusively used in the context described you could do it unconditionally, otherwise if you need to do it conditionally - expose a Boolean:

```
public var doActionAfterAppear = false

public override viewDidAppear(animated isAnimated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated: animated)
    if self.doActionAfterAppear {
        self.myAction()
        self.doActionAfterAppear = false
    }
}
```

And lastly before you present the second view controller or transition to it:

```
nextViewController. doActionAfterAppear = true
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution! It worked like a charm!

Comment: Great, please "Accept" the answer so other users know that it worked